# When Oracle database link to connect to Excel's using ODBC I have "identifier's name length exceeds maximum"

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, oracle11g

I tried to get data in Oracle from Excel using ODBC and database link. I use sql like this:

```
Select * From A222$@TEST2
```

When `TEST2` - name of Excel database link, and `A222` - name of my worksheet of Excel file.

However, because in first row of Excel I have big string values like 
`A1234567890_B1234567890_C1234567890_D1234567890_E1234567890` that converted to very big column name, and when I try to use sql like this:

```
 CREATE VIEW VIEW2 AS Select * From A222$@TEST2;
 // or 
 Select A1234567890_B1234567890_C1234567890_D1234567890_E1234567890 as c1 from A222$@TEST2;
 // or 
 Select "A1234567890_B1234567890_C1234567890_D1234567890_E1234567890" as c1 from A222$@TEST2;
```

I get following error

```
 ORA-01948: identifier's name length (31) exceeds maximum (30)
 ORA-00972: identifier is too long
```

And I can't change this Excel file or create temp copy of this file.

It's possible:

1. Using name of Excel columns like A1, AB1, Z1 instead of first row's 
   values in sql query from ODBC Excel?
2. Or something fix this problem without changing this Excel file or
   creating temp copy of this Excel's file?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I fully understand the problem.  As Oracle points out, the this `count#of#people#how#live#in#San#francisco` is not a valid Oracle name.  But do you really want a column name, particularly if it is invalid?

I am guessing you want a string *value* not a column name so use single quotes:

```
Select 'count#of#people#how#live#in#San#francisco' as c1
from A222$@TEST2;
```

Also, only one `from` per `select`.